# Root of sum of squares of three non-standard random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have three normally distributed (edit: independent) random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ with unequal mean and variance i.e. $\mu_1\neq\mu_2\neq\mu_3$ , $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2\neq\sigma_3$. I would like to compute $Y = \sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2}$.

It is my understanding that if $\mu_i=0$ and $\sigma_i=1$, $Y$ becomes a [Maxwell distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). If I understand correctly, it is also possible to obtain something called a noncentral chi distribution in the event where $\mu_i\neq0$. However, none of this seems to apply to my situation and my lack of experience in statistics leaves me clueless.

Comment: Are these 3 variable independent?

Comment: @PC1 Yes, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu_i=0$ and $\sigma_i=1$ then $Y^2$ will be a Chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of freedom (noted $\chi^2_3$ here). The positive square root is the Maxwell distribution you refer to.

As $\mu_i\ne0$ and $\sigma_i\ne1$ in general, you are then likely to want to look at the [Generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) and consider $Y^2$. However, there are usually no closed form for the pdf, cdf, etc. unless your problem has some symmetry or another feature to reduce the complexity.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Is it possible to determine the distribution of the positive square root of the generalized chi-squared distribution, which I am tempted to call the generalized chi distribution (but which doesn't seem to exist)?

Comment: Maybe, but you likely first need to find a way to represent the (non-analytic) pdf of the generalized $\chi^2$ distribution... Maybe if there are symmetries in your problem or other features then it could become tractable.

Comment: I am off to figure out how to do that, thank you very much for your time!